# Rails:How to mention same route for get and post method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rails 4 and I am using it for first time.
I have the same action for get and post request, I know I can do it as follows
`post '/auto-links', to: 'main#auto_links'`
`get '/auto-links', to: 'main#auto_links'`

But I want to know is this the only way to do this?
I tried using `match '/auto-links' => 'main#auto_links'` but it gives following error.

**You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method. If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option. If you want to expose your action to GET, use `get` in the router: Instead of: match "controller#action" Do: get "controller#action"**

Is there any other way to write only one statement that defines route to both get and post method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning just tells you to do:

```
match '/auto-links' => 'main#auto_links', via: [:get, :post]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to do it in single line

```
match 'post/:id' => 'posts#show', via: [:get, :post]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
match '/auto-links', to: 'main#auto_links', via: [:get, :post]
```